# Polimorfismo en c# con sobrecarga de metodos

Tags: c#

Intento sobrescribir el método `guardar` heredado con `override` con
diferentes cantidades de argumento pero me sale error, ya que cada clase va a tomar propiedades diferentes para guardar.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace profinal {

abstract class procesamiento 
{
    public abstract void guardar();
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string cedula { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public int telefono { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }

    public virtual void guardar(string idd, int ced, string nom, int  tel, string eml, string direc)
    {

    }
}    

class paciente : procesamiento {
     SqlConnection pro = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-1D9F71A;Initial Catalog=profinl;Integrated Security=True");
     SqlCommand comand;
     public string direccion { get; set; }

     public override void guardar(/*string idd, int ced, string nom,int tel, string eml, string direc*/){
         pro.Open();
     }    
}    

class clinica : princ {
    public string direccion { get; set; }    
}

class medico : princ {
     public string exequatur { get; set; }
     public string clinica { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Los parámetros del método guardar al hacer el `override` deben coincidir con los marcados al definir el método `abstract`. Si necesitas dos firmas diferentes, deberás definir dos métodos abstractos guardar.

Comment: Podrías editar la pregunta, e indicar el error que te da?.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando sobreescribes un metodo este debe tener la misma firma que tiene el método que estas sobreescribiendo (modificador de acceso, tipo devuelto, parámetros).  Si la firma es distinta entonces no estas sobreescribiendo sino sobrecargando el metodo por lo cual no debes usar ***override***, pero tienes que estar consciente que vas a tener el método sobrecargado en el objeto que hereda de la clase padre.

La razón de usar ***override*** no es para modificar los parámetros o el tipo devuelto, sino para tener una implementación distinta del método.

Si tienes varias clases heredando de la clase **procesamiento** y todas estas implementan una versión de guardar con distintos parámetros por que no consideras implementar en la clase padre el método **guardar** con los modificadores **private protected** y luego en las clases hijas crea una una version publica con los parametros que quieras, así no tienes sobrecargas publicas y puedes acceder desde la clase hijo a la version **guardar** de la clase padre

```
abstract class procesamiento
{
    private protected virtual void guardar(string idd, int ced, string nom, int tel, string eml, string direc)
    {
        
    }
}

class paciente : procesamiento
{
    public void guardar(string idd)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No deberías almacenar cadenas de conexión dentro de la declaración de un objeto, por lo que se deja ver, indicas el nombre del equipo por lo que solo serviría para equipos que pudieran resolver el nombre "DESKTOP-1D9F71A" de manera local y accesible.

Puedes utilizar el constructor para inicializar los valores de conexión SQL, si todos los hijos tienen conexión SQL, define el objeto en la case padre:

```
class paciente : procesamiento
{
    paciente (string conexion)
    {
        base.pro = new SqlConnection(conexion);
    }
    public override void guardar()
    {
        pro.Open(); // si tienes otras operaciones que usen comprueba el estado
        base.command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO XXX" + base.nombre , pro);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Añade tratamiento de excepciones
    }
}
```

Un mejor planteamiento sería [utilizar Entity Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savechanges?view=netframework-4.8), donde teniendo el modelo de datos SQL bien definido podrías generar el código necesario de manera más automática y heredar de las clases de datos generadas para ampliar funciones personalizadas, pudiendo [actualizar lo objectos desde tu Base de Datos SQL](https://www.mainmind.com/post/actualizar-modelo-edmx-con-los-cambios-de-la-base-de-datos) con los posibles cambios.